# MVC to web form redirection without changing URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

my requirement is, there will be one controller method, which will handle all the request, that might return MVCview/model, or it might return .ASPX page, in any case URL must be same.

something like following.

```
 public ActionResult HandleRequest()
    {
       if(Module is Converted)
       {  
          return view(ModuleName);
       }
       else
       {
   //return module.aspx page, Here I can user Redirect method but it will change URL 
    //I don't want browser's Url to be changed.
       }
    }
```

Comment: Just to clear things up, you want to have one of multiple views load through ONE URL string. The view that is loaded is based on logic not included in the URL string... Thereafter you want to load the page and still have the existing string persist. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AbdulG, yes exactly you got the point,
Let say... www.mysite.com/Controller/Action link should be able to load any view,or webform.aspx page without changing its URL.

Comment: Well you could achieve this with Partial Views. Using a template View (Probably just name it `HandleRequest` so it can be returned with your existing action). From there, you can render your partial views, with in your template, based on whatever logic you plan on using

Comment: Well, to return any view is not my concern, my concern is in some scenario I need to render .aspx page on the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Your answer is Routing.

    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx



Look at following code :

 public ActionResult Test()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return RedirectToAction("TestAspx");
        }


        public ActionResult TestAspx()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app Test aspx page.";

            return View();
        }


Here the action TestAspx() returns an TestAspx.aspx view.

And for the Routing 

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
              "TestAspx",
              "testganesh",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "TestAspx" }
              );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );


        }

Please make appropriate changes to the routing names that you need.

Hope this will help.

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Mark as right if the issue got fixed.
:)
```

Comment: Can you please brief it more, because this aspx pages will be physical file, so I don't think it'll works, and URL must not be changed.

Comment: I dont think routing will achieve what the @DotNetIsMyPower is asking